# More Nvidia problems than anything else?

Tags: discussion

In the past 3-4 months I've noticed that on the main site, there is a ratio of about 5:1 referring Nvidia graphics questions than anything else, and I'm wondering why? I do understand that NVidia being a very large distributor, there will be more people asking questions, but even with comparison to questions relating FGLRX (Or even AMD cards in general,) NVidia are around 8x more prominent and visible. Is this because NVidia drivers are more complicated, or that less people use AMD? It's also getting annoying with the 100 questions a day on the same "NVIDIA DRIVERS NOT INSTALLING.. HELLLLLPPPPPPPP" and then marking duplicate after duplicate. This is a kind of rant, and I'm sorry for that but I really don't know why so many people have questions on NVidia!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: "I really don't know why so many people have questions on NVidia!" because lots of people use nVidia GPUs.

Answer (score 3):

We should have a canonical question that we can point people to which exhausts the list of how to install Nvidia drivers using the new blessed Nvidia driver ppa.

Comment: But merging another question to an old one was not a good idea. http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers  There are very high voted obsolete answers and pointing to that question is not good any more. Now I can't mark other questions as duplicates.

Comment: @Pilot6 well that's the way the system works btw. You could always edit the old one to be correct? (You have 2k+)

Comment: Yeah, "too many wrong answers" is a cop out for us, if they're old and out of date it's up to us to fix them.

Answer (score 3):

Well, people who have no experience with Ubuntu think "I know! I'll install Ubuntu," and then it all goes downhill from there.

In all seriousness, though, I think it's a mix between inexperienced users coming to Ubuntu, the popularity of NVIDIA and the fact that NVIDIA cards tend to have bad times on Ubuntu. For whatever reason, the proprietary drivers sometimes don't work, and the generic ones sometimes fail as well.

Because NVIDIA is so popular, a lot of people using Windows have the brand. When they decide to install Ubuntu, whether because they used it sometime in the past or because they like the look of it, there's a high chance they'll have problems with NVIDIA and Ubuntu. (Sorry for the redundancy)

`inexperienced/new users` + `NVIDIA's popularity` + `NVIDIA's trouble with Ubuntu` = `many NVIDIA & Ubuntu questions`.

Comment: Yeah, that actually makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Agreed, I see many of these questions across the Internet,  not just here. Someone should just create a wiki page that we could link people to.

Comment: I feel like there are so many questions that there should be an askinvidia.com or just an invidia.stackexchange.com